# WiFi is constantly trying to connect but getting disconnected

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi

I am running Mint 17 with kernel version `3.16.0-38` on my `Asus UX305FA`. When I boot up, my WiFi tries to connect to the network, disconnects and tries again.  I can see this in the syslog. My iPhone connects fine to the wifi and occasionally after many restarts the WiFi works perfectly on my Linux box. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `journal` error messages and/or pertinent logs would be helpful to diagnose possible root of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update your kernel to 4.0+ (i.e. change your distrib) and install `fimware-linux-nonfree` (and possibly `firmware-iwlwifi` if available).

If it is not working, don't forget to toggle `F2` to activate it (NB: there is a bug with the Wifi LED, don't trust it).

Comment: Is there a way to test if the fix works without a restart or risk of wifi going down? It's just a hassle if it does because I cannot download.

Comment: It should be ok without a complete computer restart, you just need to use modprobe to unload the current driver and to load the new one. In the meantime, the wifi has to go down though.

Comment: How would you do the modprobe reload?

Comment: With all due respect (I really don't intend to be rude), the modprobe thing is well documented all over the internet and not restarting the computer is not related to your original question. Please look at it from my point of view: xrestarting your computer is easy for you and far easier for me than lokking at your computer spec, finding your wifi chipset, finding your current module, finding the name of the new replacement module and giving you the correct command to do it. Plus, this ends up being bitter for me because I really don't understand why you absolutely cannot restart your computer

Comment: However you can do just that and complement my answer ;-)

Comment: sorry didn't mean to be rude but I've been googling this for days and have had to restart my computer again and again to try to get lucky and see if the wifi works. Also just got home to try this and the packages you listed don't exist according to apt

Comment: `linux-firmware-nonfree` does but I can't find the other. From googling it appears it is included in `linux-firmware` which was already installed. I rebooted and it seemed to work so let's hope it keeps on running :)

Comment: Great then! :D I updated my answer accordingly since only `linux-firmware-nonfree` seems needed (as you said, `firmware-iwlwifi` seems now merged in `linux-firmware`).